# loop through WebView and wait for onPageFinished to complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading, webview, synchronization

i have a problem looping through WebView waiting for the WebView to load completely, fill the form of the webPage with a javascript function, and then create a image of the webView.

```
for (Integer id : idToQuery) {

    webView = new WebView(ctx);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new getDataJSForPrint(), "Android");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            String someJsonData = "Lot of Data"; //only for example

            //init function use data to fill form in webpage
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:init(" + someJsonData+ ")");

            //get html String from WebView when finished to load                
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.getHtmlFromWebView('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

}
```

Now i need to wait for getHtmlFromWebView to complete execution before pass to the other WebView, i need to create a screen of the WebView and save it like an image

```
public class getDataJSForPrint{

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getHtmlFromWebView (String html) throws DocumentException, IOException{

        //got this piece of code in another answer of stackoverflow
        File imageTemp = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmpImag.jpeg");

        webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                webView.getMeasuredHeight());
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.buildDrawingCache();

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bm);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = bm.getHeight();

        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, iHeight, paint);
        webView.draw(bigcanvas);


        if (bm != null) {
            try {
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageTemp);

                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                bm.recycle();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

I tried putting

```
synchronized (object) { object.wait(); }
```

after loadUrl and tried to notify it at the end of getHtmlFromWebView but obviously it doesn't work.

What can i do to wait for the getHtmlFromWebView to complete before the FOR loop goes to the next item?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a `for` loop is needed for your requirement. You can use `recursive` functions. Try this

```
//for ArrayList; other appropriate methods if idToQuery is not ArrayList
int count = idToQuery.size();
int index = 0;

private void loadWebView() {
webView = new WebView(ctx);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new getDataJSForPrint(), "Android");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            String someJsonData = "Lot of Data"; //only for example

            //init function use data to fill form in webpage
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:init(" + someJsonData+ ")");

            //get html String from WebView when finished to load                
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.getHtmlFromWebView('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}

//Call the loadWebView function again after the bitmap operation. Increment the index each time. Then you can compare it with total count to control how many times you wan to call    loadWebView function
public class getDataJSForPrint{

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void getHtmlFromWebView (String html) throws DocumentException, IOException{

            //got this piece of code in another answer of stackoverflow
            File imageTemp = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmpImag.jpeg");

            webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    webView.getMeasuredHeight());
            webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bm);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            int iHeight = bm.getHeight();

            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, iHeight, paint);
            webView.draw(bigcanvas);


            if (bm != null) {
                try {
                    OutputStream fOut = null;
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageTemp);

                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    bm.recycle();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            index++;
            if (index < count) {
                loadWebView()
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: i tried your code but getHtmlFromWebView is never called, trying to put breakpoints around seems to ignore the java/javascript method :(, i'll check now for my code errors (i tried it very fast)

Comment: ooook, i found a solution, was my mistake with some lines of code, thank you very much, recursion is the way :D